# Valgrind complaining possible memory leak in std string's new operator

Tags: c++, valgrind, jsoncpp

In my project i am using jsoncpp, boost and many libraries, when i ran the valgrind for my program in many palces including jsoncpp, boost libraries it shows possible memory leak in string creation

I have pasted the valgrind error snippets

> ==5506== 427,198 bytes in 489 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 8,343 of 8,359
>
> ==5506==    at 0x4C2B1C7: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
>
> ==5506==    by 0x9360A88: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
>
> ==5506==    by 0x55EB0BD: char* std::string::_S_construct(char const*, char const*, std::allocator const&, std::forward_iterator_tag) (basic_string.tcc:140)
>
> ==5506==    by 0x936261C: std::basic_string, std::allocator >::basic_string(char
>   const*, unsigned long, std::allocator const&) (in
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
>
> ==5506==    by 0x63FEB99: Json::Value::asString() const (json_value.cpp:611)

My question is are these errors are valid or they are false positive ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: check (json_value.cpp:611), maybe std::string itself is 'possibly lost' (allocated by new, part of `union` etc.)

Comment: @Hcorg I checked the line((json_value.cpp:611) it  is 'return std::string(this_str, this_len);'    The 'this_str' is a char const* str and 'this_len' is unsigned i don't find them as leak source

Comment: Where is your [testcase](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be completely sure, you can do a looped test and check for memory hogging.

We had similar messages and they turned out to be false positives, so we added them to the suppression list.

Answer (score 1):

Valgrind has some heuristics that reduces the number of 'false positive'
possibly lost.

A.o., it has an heuristic to better detect std::string.

Use the following options to activate some heuristics:
       --leak-check-heuristics=heur1,heur2,... which heuristics to use for
            improving leak search false positive [none]
            where heur is one of:
              stdstring length64 newarray multipleinheritance all none

Note that in the upcoming 3.11 release, the default for this option
has been changed from 'none' to 'all'.